# If condition for XML Parser condition

Tags: java, if-statement, xmlpullparser

This  condition is true then why its showing toast for

```
if(objBean.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("4") && objBean.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("2")
                                && objBean.getDesc().equalsIgnoreCase("0") && objBean.getPubDate().equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(A.this, "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
```

then why its showing toast for this below

```
 {
       Toast.makeText(A.this, "out", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
```

**see the image below for more clearity-**
[image]

- **UPDATE-1**

**Above this image condition i have tested this below condition**

```
            if( objBean.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("4") && objBean.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("2") 
                    && objBean.getDesc().equalsIgnoreCase("0") && objBean.getPubDate() == null){


                imageButtonO.setImageResource(R.drawable.booked);
                imageButtonO.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else if(objBean.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("4") && objBean.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("2")
                    && objBean.getDesc().equalsIgnoreCase("0") && objBean.getPubDate().equalsIgnoreCase("M") ){


                imageButtonO.setImageResource(R.drawable.booked);
                imageButtonO.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else if(objBean.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("4") && objBean.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("2")
                    && objBean.getDesc().equalsIgnoreCase("0") && objBean.getPubDate().equalsIgnoreCase("F") ){

                imageButtonO.setImageResource(R.drawable.fe);
                imageButtonO.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else if(objBean.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("4") && objBean.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("2")
                    && objBean.getDesc().equalsIgnoreCase("1") )
            {

                //some condition
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity_dom.this, "not filled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

and this just above code this code run successfully-

```
else if(objBean.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("4") && objBean.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("2")
                            && objBean.getDesc().equalsIgnoreCase("0") && objBean.getPubDate().equalsIgnoreCase("F") ){

                        imageButtonO.setImageResource(R.drawable.fe);
                        imageButtonO.setEnabled(false);
```

}

- **UPDATE-2**

[image]

Comment: @RC. see my UPDATE-2 Please

Comment: No. I gave you an answer to your original question, and some advice on how to clarify your code to help **you** understand it. So please stop @-ing me. And by the way, AFAIK, java if-else is not broken, so..

Answer (score 1):

The "out" toast is showing up because if you enter the first "if" then  `objBean.getTitle()` is "2" **and** `objBean.getDesc()` is "1", **so** the second if cannot be true.

Comment: see my UPDATE-1 in the question